# Is there any option to add a scale bar to the map?

Tags: azure-maps

Is there any option to add a scale bar to the map?

I read the documentation but I couldn't find anything about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in scale bar yet, but we do plan to add a control for this soon. I'll take a look at creating a code sample on how to create a custom one.

**Update**: I've added a code sample to the official Azure Maps code sample gallery here: https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net/?sample=Simple%20Scale%20Bar%20Control